# Sitecore Forms onclick of back button clearing data

Tags: sitecore-forms, javascript, mvc-forms, ajax

I have a country field in Sitecore Forms which gets data populated from AJAX call on page load.
[image]

When I enter all the values in the form and navigation to next page all the fields looks fine.
I am facing issues when I am clicking on the back button and going to the previous page the data populated on the country field is removed.

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you get any console error when you clicked the back button?

Comment: No console error @Sumit Bhatia

Comment: Is "Advanced settings -> AJAX" disabled or enabled for your form on the Settings tab? If AJAX is disabled on a multipage form then use of the browser's back button will lead to data loss.